# Apparently weird compilation error using org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity. Different behavior in two different projects

Tags: java, android

I copied a code that worked fine in an Eclipse Java project to an Android project, and even though I import the same .jars, I get compilation errors in the Android project.

In the Android project, Eclipse shows the error "*The constructor StringEntity(String, String, String) is undefined*" in the following line:

```
StringEntity se = new StringEntity("example data.", "application/json", "UTF-8");
```

But in the other Java project, it compiles and runs fine. The [documentation](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/StringEntity.html) says that the constructor `StringEntity(String string, String mimeType, String charset)` does exist.

I'm importing the same `org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity` in the two projects. The jars used in the Eclipse project are the same used in the Android project. I even copied and pasted them. I cleaned the project too. Still no success. Can anyone please explain to me why this error is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android doesn't use the latest version of HttpClient 4.x.

The [Android version of `StringEntity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/entity/StringEntity.html) currently only has these constructors:

- `StringEntity(String s, String charset)`
- `StringEntity(String s)`

I assume that the Android SDK classes are taking precedence over the same classes you provide as JARs. I'd remove the JARs to avoid this kind of confusion in the future -- having different versions of the same classes never did anyone good.

Comment: I didn't realize there was a `StringEntity`in Android. I organized the order of imports, putting my imported jars on top and the error disappeared. Thanks. Your answer helped me learned that the imports order matters.

Comment: Please **remove** any HTTPClient JAR from your Android app! Having two versions of HTTPClient classes around will cause all kinds of crazy problems. Try to use what Android has, if it really doesn't work look at the source code of the "official" HTTPClient and cherrypick the changes you want, implement them in your code.

Comment: Yes, I already removed. I caused problems, indeed. I'll use what Android has available. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your projects are more than likely using different versions of Apache Http Components. That library comes baked into Android and its rarely the latest released version. The actual version your are currently using will be dictated by the version of Android you are working against.

Comment: Are you sure the old version of HttpComponents is not still in your build path?